# Finding the top most(z-order) control in a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

See my case is,

I am opening more than one `forms (toplevel=false)` inside a `panel`. All the `forms` opened inside that `panel` will be `dock filled` and `brought to front` during runtime. and my need in this situation is, how can i select the top most control(`form`) on that `panel`. Top most control means control(`form`) which is having greater `z-order`.

I am currently using this code by assumption,

```
 panel.controls(0)
```

Can any body tell me, whether the above snippet is right or any alternate syntax available in dot net to achieve that.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx):

> The control with an index value of zero is at the top of the z-order, and higher numbers are closer to the bottom.

Therefore, I'd say your assumption was correct.  `Controls(0)` will always be the top-most control.  The only concern would be whether or not it is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other solution of looping through each Control and see what's the topmost one.
Something like:

```
Dim TopMostControl As Control = panel.Controls(0) 'Check if there are any control
For Each Control As Control In panel.Controls
    If panel.Controls.GetChildIndex(Control) < panel.Controls.GetChildIndex(TopMostControl) Then
        TopMostControl = Control
    End If
Next
```